# Create Schema in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, database-schema

I am trying to create a new Schema in Oracle 11g.

I have referred to the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6014.htm)

I have tried to execute the commands mentioned there.

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION oe

   CREATE TABLE new_product 

      (color VARCHAR2(10)  PRIMARY KEY, quantity NUMBER) 

   CREATE VIEW new_product_view 

      AS SELECT color, quantity FROM new_product WHERE color = 'RED' 

   GRANT select ON new_product_view TO hr;
```

I am getting the following error when I run this commands in Eclipse.

***ORA-02421: missing or invalid schema authorization identifier
(0 rows affected)***

***Elapsed Time:  0 hr, 0 min, 0 sec, 0 ms.***

Anybody has an idea why this is happening ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At at a guess, I'd say you're not logged in as user `oe` (which the docs you reference say you must be).

Also see [the description of the error you're getting](http://ora-02421.ora-code.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Go to Command Prompt. Login as System and Password as orcl

SQL> create user [username] identified by [password];

User created.

SQL> grant create session to [username];

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create table to [username];

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create role developer;

Role created.

SQL> grant developer to [username];

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant resource to [username];

Comment: I think this is the better answer regarding creating schema, in Oracle schema = user.